# How to restore a save file from tape if the user profile storage allocation is insufficient?

Tags: storage, profile, ibm-midrange

I am trying to restore a very large save file from tape on AS/400. The save file is restored with a profile which is not the one used to save the object. The restoration is conducted by calling an adoption program to gain the full authority of the save file owner profile so in the end the save file owner will be changed to the one I need. The problem is that the owner profile of the save file does not have sufficient storage allocation(the save file was originally saved from another LPAR under the same user profile which does not have this problem), though the other profile has sufficient storage. Due to various reason, increasing the storage limit of the owner profile is not possible. So is there any other method to get around the storage constraint? Restoring the save file under QDFTOWN then changing it back is too time consuming in my company so I would not really take this approach. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You might want to consult the folks at the Midrange-L mailing list (midrange.com).

Comment: No, there is no trick.  Have your admin increase the storage allocation of the restoring profile.  Then you will be following company protocol and the admin will be aware that this profile has temporary higher storage requirements.